# Issues with binding using Telerik and ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, reactiveui

I understand if this question is too specific to the telerik controls product, but any help would be appreciated.

I am having some issues with binding to telerik combo box inside a dataform.

I am setting the item source of the comboboxfield to a collection pulled from a database.  I wish to update the EditableModel with the JobID from the selected drop down value.

I require the Selected Item of the combobox to be set to the matching Id as stored in the JobID property.

I have had a play around with this but can't seem to get the values to bind correctly.
​

View Model

```
public class EditableViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public EditableModel SelectedEntity { get; set; }
    public List<JobModel> Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

​

Models

```
public class EditableModel
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int JobId { get; set; }
}

public class JobModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

VIEW

```
<reactiveui:ReactiveWindow 
    x:Class="TestWpfApplication.MainWindow"
    x:TypeArguments="test:EditableViewModel"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:test="clr-namespace:TestWpfApplication.ViewModels"
    xmlns:reactiveui="http://reactiveui.net"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
    Title="NuGet Browser" Height="450" Width="800"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
                <StackPanel>
                    <telerik:DataFormDataField  Label="First Name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
                    <telerik:DataFormComboBoxField  Label="Job" SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding JobId, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Jobs, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <telerik:RadDataForm AutoGenerateFields="False" x:Name="RadDataForm" EditTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"/>
    </Grid>
</reactiveui:ReactiveWindow>
```

​

Comment: Where is the `Jobs` property defined?

Comment: I have updated the snippet sorry about that

Comment: Did you set or bound the `CurrentItem` property of the `RadDataForm` to an `EditableViewModel`?

Comment: I don't see any use of INotifyPropertyChange, also might be worthwhile using a ObservableCollection instead of a List since the UI has no way of knowing if the list has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.  My DataContext binding was not being setup correctly